# Forward URL information from parent to child iframe

Tags: javascript, html, url, redirect, iframe

I need to come up with a way to forward block information from our school's internet filter to our school's internal web server. The final page will just be a normal html page, but with a iframe in the center that allows faculty members to login to override the internet filter.

When the filter first blocks a page, it sends the user to
`http://extranet.test.org/blocked.html?URL=http://test.8e6.net/&IP=4.4.4.4&CAT=GPORN&USER=IPGROUP` Where everything after the ? is information that the iframe MUST have at the end in it's URL.

In the parent page's html, how do I specify that the iframe should go to `http://google.com/block.html`with the stuff after the `?` from the parent page?  So in the end the iframe should end up being `http://google.com/block.html?URL=http://test.8e6.net/&IP=4.4.4.4&CAT=GPORN&USER=IPGROUP`.

Comment: you are most likely mistaken in that the part after the `&` belongs to the first url and not the second.. the `&IP=4.4.4.4&CAT=GPORN&USER=IPGROUP`

Answer (score 1):

In other words, you you to use JavaScript to create an iframe that includes the query string from the parent page.

Oddly enough, in JavaScript, the query string is in `window.location.search`, and it includes the `?` character. This means you could copy it into an iframe with this code:

```
​<iframe id="bypass-login"/>​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
<script>
  loginIframe = document.getElementById("bypass-login");
  loginIframe.src="http://google.com/block.html" + window.location.search​;
</script>
```